# Как мне сделать что бы только при нажатии Enter программа продолжала работу?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));

    int q[3];  
    int start = 0, ends = 0;  

    cout << "Enter: " << endl;

    for (int h = 0; h < 3; h++) {

        int a;
        a = rand() % 10;
        q[start++] = a;  
    }

    cout << "First: " << q[start - 1] << endl;
    cout << "Second: " << q[start - 2] << endl;
    cout << "Last: " << q[ends];
    cout << endl;

    // Это должно высвечивать только когда я нажму Enter 
    if (q[start - 1] == q[start - 2])
    {
        cout << "q[start - 1] == q[start - 2]" << endl;
    }

    if (q[start - 1] == q[ends])
    {
        cout << "q[start - 1] == q[ends]" << endl;
    }

    if (q[start - 2] == q[ends])
    {
        cout << "q[start - 2] == q[ends]" << endl;
    }

    if (q[start - 1] == q[start - 2] == q[ends])
    {
        cout << "WOW!!!" << endl;
    }


    if (start != ends) cout << "Queue is empy!"; 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: А сейчас что происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
printf("\nPress Enter...");
char anykey[120];
gets_s(anykey, sizeof(anykey));
```

Ввод завершится по нажатию Enter, но буфер стоит делать с запасом, потому что при переполнении будет ошибка. Ошибку можно обработать самому через установку своего [constraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s), но проще сделать буфер побольше.

*(поправил ошибку, поленился сразу код проверить)*